# How to remove column in Pentaho Data Integration?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am using PDI/Kettle. I know it is possible to add new columns by specifying them in fields. Is it possible to remove deprecated input columns coming from the previous step in Modified Javascript Step with Spoon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Select / Rename values` step to remove any field from record stream.

- Do it in a 2nd tab `Remove` where you define `Fields to remove`

Answer (score 0):

@Hello-lad

Reading your question looks like you wanted to know specifically if you can discard an input column coming from a previous step inside of a Modified Javascript Step, but the real use of this transformation is to create columns derived from values coming in the stream of Pentaho and not really to eliminate unwanted items in that stream, for that you particularly use the Select / Rename values (as indicated by mzy)